# I'm trying to deploy a backend server on elastic beanstalk and when I use the link it get 502 bad gateway

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, backend

I'm trying to deploy a backend server on elastic beanstalk and when I use the link it get 502 bad gateway

it's a node.js and express server

here is the log output

```
/var/log/nginx/access.log
----------------------------------------
172.31.90.144 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:20:35 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.18.237 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:20:35 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.40.18 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:20:43 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 559 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "41.69.184.245"
172.31.40.18 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:20:44 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 502 559 "http://project1-env.eba-cjrmrczb.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "41.69.184.245"
172.31.40.18 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:20:50 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.90.144 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:20:50 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.18.237 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:20:50 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.90.144 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:21:05 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.40.18 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:21:05 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.18.237 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:21:05 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.40.18 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:21:20 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.90.144 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:21:20 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.18.237 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:21:20 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.40.18 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:21:35 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.90.144 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:21:35 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.18.237 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:21:35 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.40.18 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:21:50 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.90.144 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:21:50 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.18.237 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:21:50 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.40.18 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:22:05 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.90.144 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:22:05 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.18.237 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:22:05 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.40.18 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:22:20 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.90.144 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:22:20 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.18.237 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:22:20 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.40.18 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:22:35 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.90.144 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:22:35 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.18.237 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:22:35 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.40.18 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:22:50 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.90.144 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:22:50 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.18.237 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:22:50 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.40.18 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:23:05 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.90.144 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:23:05 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.18.237 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:23:05 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.90.144 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:23:08 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "Expanse, a Palo Alto Networks company, searches across the global IPv4 space multiple times per day to identify customers&#39; presences on the Internet. If you would like to be excluded from our scans, please send IP addresses/domains to: scaninfo@paloaltonetworks.com" "205.210.31.13"
172.31.40.18 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:23:20 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.90.144 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:23:20 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.18.237 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:23:20 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.40.18 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:23:35 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.90.144 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:23:35 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.18.237 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:23:35 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.40.18 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:23:50 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.90.144 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:23:50 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.18.237 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:23:50 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.40.18 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:24:05 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.90.144 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:24:05 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.18.237 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:24:05 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.40.18 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:24:20 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.90.144 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:24:20 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.18.237 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:24:20 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.40.18 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:24:35 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.90.144 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:24:35 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.18.237 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:24:35 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.40.18 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:24:50 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.90.144 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:24:50 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.18.237 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:24:50 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.40.18 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:25:05 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.90.144 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:25:05 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.18.237 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:25:05 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.40.18 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:25:20 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.90.144 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:25:20 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.18.237 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:25:20 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.40.18 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:25:35 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.90.144 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:25:35 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.18.237 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:25:35 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.40.18 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:25:50 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.18.237 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:25:50 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.90.144 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:25:50 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.40.18 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:26:05 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.18.237 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:26:05 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.90.144 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:26:05 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.40.18 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:26:20 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.18.237 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:26:20 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.90.144 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:26:20 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.40.18 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:26:35 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.90.144 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:26:35 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.18.237 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:26:35 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.40.18 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:26:50 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.90.144 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:26:50 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.18.237 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:26:51 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.40.18 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:27:05 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.90.144 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:27:06 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.18.237 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:27:06 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.40.18 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:27:21 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.90.144 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:27:21 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.18.237 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:27:21 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.40.18 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:27:36 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.90.144 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:27:36 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.18.237 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:27:36 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.40.18 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:27:51 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.90.144 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:27:51 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.18.237 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:27:51 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.40.18 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:28:06 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.90.144 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:28:06 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.18.237 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:28:06 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.40.18 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:28:21 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.90.144 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:28:21 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.18.237 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:28:21 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.90.144 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:28:26 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 559 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "41.69.184.245"
172.31.90.144 - - [27/Jan/2023:20:28:27 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 502 559 "http://project1-env.eba-cjrmrczb.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "41.69.184.245"
```

i have tried to set env variable `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true` but still nothing changed and i have tried to create .ebextensions folder in my root folder and add nodecommand.config but when i do so the project doesn't perform deploy anymore

Comment: what link? can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. It turns out that I forgot to include the `dist` folder in my deployment.